# A finite group of order $n$ has exponent $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

> Definitions: The *order* $|G|$ of a group $G$ is the number of elements of $G$. The *exponent* of a group is an integer $n$ such that $x^n = e$ for all $x\in G$ ($e$ is the neutral element).

Particularly, the definition doesn't say it's the least integer with the property. So in this definition the 4-group $V$ has exponent $4$ as well as exponent $2$.

But I'm having a hard time proving the following statement:

> Lagrange's Theorem shows that a finite group $G$ of order $n$ has exponent $n$.

I know it must be very simple because it's not even stated as a corollary of Lagrange's.

Comment: What does Lagrange's Theorem state?

Comment: Because the order of an element $g\in G$ divides the order of the group! Hence, if $g^{ord(g)}=1$ and $ord(g)*m=n$ then $g^n=g^{ord(g)m}=g^n=(g^{ord(g)})^m=1^m=1$!

Comment: The definition **does** say it is the least integer with that property.

Comment: Guido is right, see [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponent+of+a+group). Also, immediately after Lagrange we find $a^{|G|}=e$ in all algebra books (sometimes called Euler).

Comment: I just typed a remark of an algebra book (Rotman's Introduction to the theory of groups).